# approach to SELECT likes/dislikes for each product in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d31c6a/19)

I have two tables to store users' likes/dislikes on products. I pull up the number of likes and dislikes for each toy on a page using `RIGHT JOIN`. I'd like to know if it's an appropriate approach to get this output:

```
TOY   LIKES DISLIKES
ToyA    2   0
ToyB    0   0
ToyC    0   0
ToyD    1   2
ToyE    0   0
ToyF    0   0
ToyG    0   1
ToyH    1   0
ToyI    0   0
```

Another approach I've come up is to store the number of likes/dislikes in table `toy` so that it doesn't need a RIGHT JOIN, but it requires an additional insert query when someone votes. Which one would you prefer?

```
   SELECT 
          b.toy,
          IFNULL(SUM( liketype =1 ),0)AS likes, 
          IFNULL(SUM( liketype =0 ),0) AS dislikes
          FROM `product_review` a 
          RIGHT JOIN toy b
          ON b.ID = a.toyid 
          GROUP BY b.toy
```

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE toy
    (`ID` int, `toy` varchar(21), `like` int ,`dislike` int)
;

INSERT INTO toy
    (`ID`,`toy`, `like`,`dislike`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ToyA', 2, 0),
    (2, 'ToyB',0 , 0),
    (3, 'ToyC', 0, 0),
    (4, 'ToyD', 1, 2),
    (5, 'ToyE', 0, 0),
    (6, 'ToyF', 0, 0),
    (7, 'ToyG',0, 1),
    (8, 'ToyH',0, 1),
    (9, 'ToyI', 0, 0)
;



CREATE TABLE product_review
    (`ID` int,`user` varchar(20), `toyid` varchar(21), `liketype` int)
;

INSERT INTO product_review
    (`ID`, `user`,`toyid`, `liketype`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom','1', 1),
    (2, 'Ben', '4',0),
    (3, 'Peter','1', 1),
    (4, 'May','4', 0),
    (5, 'May', '8',1),
    (6, 'Tom','7',0),
    (7, 'Paul','4', 1)
;
```

Comment: Storing aggregate likes might be helpful if you end up having a very large user base, but it shouldn't matter for a small site. If you do an aggregate table you shouldn't insert when a user likes or dislikes a product, but run a query to sum the `product_review` table periodically. (for example, what would happen if a user likes a product repeatedly, or likes, then dislikes the same product repeatedly?)

Comment: Hooray for poor, neglected RIGHT JOIN !

Comment: Just store the toy_id, the user_id and a flag ("1" or "0") to say whether they "liked" or "disliked" it. You could call that column 'liked', if you liked

Answer (score 1):

If the number of user votes is too much & you need to calculate & show result of voting many times, then this joining may be an overhead. At the other side, storing vote informations in a separate table would be more flexible. So I personally prefer to mix two solutions:
Keep `product_review` table & add the number of like/dislikes in the toy table, then add a trigger on `product_review` table to update like/dislike field for corresponding toy in `toy` table after every vote record insertion. This acts like a cache for you and helps you to benefit two solutions in the same time.